# Why do I get errors while terminating ActorSystem?

Tags: here-olp

I create DataClient:

```
ActorSystem actorSystem = ExtendedActorSystem.apply();
com.here.platform.data.client.javadsl.DataClient dataClient = com.here.platform.data.client.javadsl.DataClient.get(actorSystem);
    Settings defaultSettings = dataClient.defaultSettings();

    HereAccountRequestSignerSettings hereAccountRequestSignerSettings =
            new HereAccountRequestSignerSettings.Builder()
                    .withHereClientId(credentials.getHereClientId())
                    .withHereAccessKeyId(credentials.getHereAccessKeyId())
                    .withHereAccessKeySecret(credentials.getHereAccessKeySecret())
                    .build();

    Settings settings = defaultSettings
            .withRequestSignerSettings(hereAccountRequestSignerSettings);

    queryApi = dataClient.queryApi(hrn, settings);
    readEngine = DataEngine.get(actorSystem).readEngine(hrn, settings);
```

After all operations I try to terminate my ActorSystem:

```
CoordinatedShutdown.get(actorSystem).run(CoordinatedShutdown.unknownReason());
```

But I get these errors:

```
[ERROR] [02/06/2020 18:03:10.079] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-25] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(default)] Outgoing request stream error (akka.stream.AbruptTerminationException: Processor actor [Actor[akka://default/system/StreamSupervisor-1/flow-16-0-mergePreferred#-1223493945]] terminated abruptly)
[ERROR] [02/06/2020 18:03:10.080] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-25] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(default)] Outgoing request stream error (akka.stream.AbruptTerminationException: Processor actor [Actor[akka://default/system/StreamSupervisor-1/flow-16-0-mergePreferred#-1223493945]] terminated abruptly)
```

Comment: What version of the SDK (or Maven BOM) are you using?